# Passing an installed file (.reg) to program (regedit) in Inno Setup fails with "Cannot import ... Error opening the file"

Tags: installation, registry, inno-setup, pascalscript, regedit

I would like to import a reg file after installing. Here is my code:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
Var
    ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    if CurStep = ssPostInstall then begin
        Exec('{win}\regedit.exe', '{app}\MyReg.reg', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    end;
end;
```

I also tried this:

```
[Run]
Filename "{win}\regedit.exe"; Parameters: "{app}\MyReg.reg";
```

Both fail with:

> Cannot import MyReg.reg: Error opening the file. There may be a disk or file system error.

I tried to import reg file manually (`cmd.exe`)

```
C:\Windows\regedit.exe MyReg.reg
```

Comment: @Martin, don't worry to generalize the thread title and basic description (and the specific problem mention as a what *"I've tried and what failed example"*). I could find many threads about this topic around. But since they are not searchable, the OP probably asked this question (with the same solution again).

Comment: Rather than trying to import a .reg file after install, you should convert the file to `[Registry]` entries within Inno instead.  This way you don't need to distribute the reg file, and you get better logging (and the ability to mark some entries to be uninstalled).  Some third-party tools exist to automatically convert reg files to `[Registry]` entries, but they're not hard to convert manually as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are installing to `Program Files`, then the `{app}` contains spaces.

You should always wrap paths to double quotes to allow paths with spaces.

```pascal
Exec('{win}\regedit.exe', '"{app}\MyReg.reg"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

Similarly:

```
[Run]
Filename "{win}\regedit.exe"; Parameters: """{app}\MyReg.reg""";
```